# JRBeanCollectionDataSource - Unknown property 'notas' on class 'class model.Notas'

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm trying to fill a report with a datasource and i'm getting this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean : notas
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:123)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getFieldValue(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:96)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource.getFieldValue(JRBeanCollectionDataSource.java:100)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setOldValues(JRFillDataset.java:1331)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1232)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1208)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.next(JRBaseFiller.java:1577)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:149)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:932)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:864)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:88)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:653)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:569)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:915)
    at NewMain.generarNotas(NewMain.java:38)
    at NewMain.main(NewMain.java:66)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'notas' on class 'class model.Notas'
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1322)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:770)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:846)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:426)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:111)
    ... 15 more
```

This is my jrxml source

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report name" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="020115f1-3bfe-4a04-bd2a-4167b98b9732">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0000000000000004"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <subDataset name="notasDS" uuid="50c79efe-5519-47b6-ad00-c2f0e7ee7c09">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="descripcionUsuario" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[descripcionUsuario]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="descripcionNota" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[descripcionNota]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="fechaDeRegistro" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[fechaDeRegistro]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <field name="notas" class="java.util.Collection"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="37" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="ef4eae36-66dd-4e97-be61-65e6dd13b896" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="35"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial Black" size="24" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[NOTAS]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="26" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="97256cf0-c9fe-4422-99aa-bbbb81232db3" x="2" y="1" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[fechaDeRegistro]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="065b2f0c-afbd-4110-ba24-054f60994e6a" x="102" y="1" width="237" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[descripcionNota]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="0add16bc-37b7-40e2-ab6d-8b2933b73cf8" x="339" y="1" width="216" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[descripcionUsuario]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="21" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement uuid="5fc40798-8e9a-4d07-b273-acc91b4147ec" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="21"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="notasDS" uuid="98a1a836-2fc0-42e2-9ada-f3eea1c4ecba">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{notas})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="21" width="555">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="d95ff7e4-4075-47be-b742-69af661799b6" x="2" y="1" width="100" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{fechaDeRegistro}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="5a6e3c78-7d57-4f8d-8e5e-bc34e0740b1c" x="102" y="1" width="237" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{descripcionNota}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="514ec211-8001-4201-bdd8-78d6d533315b" x="339" y="1" width="216" height="20"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{descripcionUsuario}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

This is the class i'm trying to pass

```java
package model;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Notas implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 48L;
    private Integer codNota;
    private String descripcionNota;
    private String descripcionUsuario;
    private String fechaDeRegistro;
    private Boolean notForDelete;
    private Boolean descripcionUsuarioMandatory = Boolean.FALSE;

    public Notas() {
    }
    public Notas(Integer codNota) {
        this.codNota = codNota;
    }
    public Notas(Integer codNota, String descripcionNota, String descripcionUsuario, String fechaDeRegistro) {
        this.codNota = codNota;
        this.descripcionNota = descripcionNota;
        this.descripcionUsuario = descripcionUsuario;
        this.fechaDeRegistro = fechaDeRegistro;
        this.notForDelete = Boolean.FALSE;
        this.descripcionUsuarioMandatory = Boolean.FALSE;
    }

    public Notas getMe() {
        return this;
    }

    public Integer getCodNota() {
        return codNota;
    }

    public void setCodNota(Integer codNota) {
        this.codNota = codNota;
    }

    public String getDescripcionNota() {
        return descripcionNota;
    }

    public void setDescripcionNota(String descripcionNota) {
        this.descripcionNota = descripcionNota;
    }

    public String getDescripcionUsuario() {
        return descripcionUsuario;
    }

    public void setDescripcionUsuario(String descripcionUsuario) {
        this.descripcionUsuario = descripcionUsuario;
    }

    public String getFechaDeRegistro() {
        return fechaDeRegistro;
    }

    public void setFechaDeRegistro(String fechaDeRegistro) {
        this.fechaDeRegistro = fechaDeRegistro;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (codNota != null ? codNota.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Notas)) {
            return false;
        }
        Notas other = (Notas) object;
        if ((this.codNota == null && other.codNota != null) 
                || (this.codNota != null && !this.codNota.equals(other.codNota))
                || (this.descripcionUsuario == null && other.descripcionUsuario != null) 
                || (this.descripcionUsuario != null && !this.descripcionUsuario.equals(other.descripcionUsuario))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "co.gov.rnec.srcw.model.Notas[ codNota=" + codNota + " ]";
    }

    public Boolean getNotForDelete() {
        return notForDelete;
    }

    public void setNotForDelete(Boolean notForDelete) {
        this.notForDelete = notForDelete;
    }

    public Boolean getDescripcionUsuarioMandatory() {
        return descripcionUsuarioMandatory;
    }

    public void setDescripcionUsuarioMandatory(Boolean descripcionUsuarioMandatory) {
        this.descripcionUsuarioMandatory = descripcionUsuarioMandatory;
    }
}
```

And this is how i pass the collection of beans

```java
List notas = Arrays.asList(
    new Notas(new Integer("1"), "CORRECCION", "DE nombre", "24/01/2013"),
    new Notas(new Integer("5"), "SERIAL", "Cancelado", "25/12/2012"),
    new Notas(new Integer("6"), "CAMBIOS", "En los nombres", "26/10/2012"),
    new Notas(new Integer("7"), "DECRETO", "8", "27/12/2012")
);

Map parameters = new HashMap();
parameters.put("ReportTitle", "Notas");
parameters.put("DataFile", "Notas.java - Bean Collection");

JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport("Notas.jasper", 
        parameters, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(notas, false));

JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "D:\\Notas.pdf");
```

In the report the only 'notas' i have is the field for the data source.

Can someone hep to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: The declaration of *notas* field is wrong. Your JavaBean does not contain the *getNotas()* public method. You can look at [JavaBean Data Sources](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/datasource/index.html#javabeandatasources) sample for better understanding how to use *JavaBean datasource*

Comment: Thanks, that was my problem. Idelete the field notas and add the the atributtes of the class in the field sections of the report

Answer (score 1):

I lost a lot of time trying to figure out what was happening, after a few hours I iterated the List I was passing as the DataSource and realised I hadn't **cast** the list to the **correct type**. Give it a try iterating the list before sending it to the report.